# Oracle SQL Select: If not exist, leave blank

Tags: database, sql

I have two tables:

```
Table1
[ID]   [Number]
1      40
2      100
3      7
```

and

```
Table2
[ID]   [Number]   [Name]
1      40         A
3      7          C
```

Data originates in Table1, then gets copied to Table2 (with an added Name) after some processes are completed. I'm trying to `SELECT` everything in Table1 while also showing the Name field from Table2, if it exists. If the Name field doesn't exist (or more correctly, if the ID doesn't yet exist in Table2), I want to leave the field blank.

Desired output:

```
[ID]   [Number]   [Name]
1      40         A
2      100
3      7          C
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT Table1.ID,Table1.Number,Table2.Name
WHERE Table1.ID=Table2.ID
```

My current attempts have completely omitted `[ID] 2` since the statement I'm trying is looking for the ID in both tables and only finds it in Table1. My guess is I may need to use `COALESCE`, `ISNULL`, or a `JOIN`, all of which are foreign to me. Are any of these (or combination of many) the right tools for the job? Is there a way I can include the `Name` field only if it exists, and otherwise leave it blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you have to use an outer join (example in Syntax valid since Oracle 9i):

```
SELECT
  Table1.ID,
  Table1.Number,
  Table2.Name
FROM Table1
OUTER JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

**Update**

To explain things a bit more (as mentioned by duDE):

The join used in the question is called equi-join, this means that only rows in `Table1` are selected that also exists in `Table2` (and vice versa).

The outer join selects all rows contained in `Table1` and joins all matching rows from `Table2`. If `Table2` does not contain a matching row then `null` is returned for all columns.

Comment: With a small explanation of OUTER JOIN would be the perfect answer, smth like "An outer join is a join similar to the equi join, but Oracle will also return non matched rows from the table. " . Nevertheless +1 from me :)